# Threads keep running even after test finishes in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running 24 Hr load test on jmeter with 3256 threads. But even after 28 hrs some of the threads keep running and does not get ramp down. There are several errors in the run.

Even when I choose to stop the threads,"Shutting down all the threads, please be patient" Pop up appears and stays forever and no threads are ramping down.

For your information:- Number of threads-3256; Ramp up period-300; Loop Count-192 
Considering all the think/wait time in the script , scenario should run for 24Hrs.

How can I close all the threads forcefully.

Comment: How can you be so sure that test will end in 24 hrs? calculating from think time and wait times is completely illogical. You can't predict response times and thus test duration (comment if you have statistical calculations). Try providing test duration manually as 24 hrs and then check and don't expect sharp 24 hrs, +-10-15 mins are ok.

Comment: Are you running test with 3256 threads? what is your machine config? is that a single machine or cluster or cloud? If you are running that from a single machine then again it is obvious to see such issues and hung cases. split load on multiple machine and try distributed testing.

Comment: Threads are open even after 48Hrs. I am running test from 16 other Jmeter machins, but only in few of them threads are not closing. I have allocated 4GB memory to Jmter. Total RAM is 8GB.

Comment: I am even not able to take a thread dump of Jmeter using jstack. If you have idea regarding that please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There are following options available:

1. JMeter is listening to shutdown messages on port 4445. There are 2 scripts in /bin folder of your JMeter installation:

   - shutdown.cmd(sh) - send graceful shutdown request to all threads
   - stoptest.cmd(sh) - force stop threads
2. Use [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler "Stop Now" option for "All Threads"
3. Use [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) with the following code:

   ```
   SampleResult.setStopTestNow(true);
   ```

However in that way you can get lots of errors caused by force shutting down of test threads which will be in your test results.

Actually I think that behavior your're experiencing is being caused by lack of resources on your load generator (JMeter) side. Try following recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide to see if it helps (you don't need to wait all 24h, it will be enough to wait till all threads are ramped up).

If adjusting JMeter parameters won't help it looks like that you'll need to consider [distributed](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) testing and generate the load from more than one host.