# Jmeter master slave not all threads finishing

Tags: jmeter

I have a master/slave for jmeter set up using jmeter 5.1
For time to time I am noticing the tests just hangs up while waiting for threads to shutdown.

In the jmeter.logs I am seeing:

2020-02-06 00:06:35,100 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +      9 in 00:30:34 =    0.0/s Avg:  5647 Min:  5520 Max:  5833 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 4 Finished: 3

I tried waiting but it never finishes this 1 active thread and it causes issue for rest of the steps I have in the pipeline to read the jmeter test result file and generate HTML report.

Any suggestions how to debug this?

I saw this post:
[Threads keep running even after test finishes in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710463/threads-keep-running-even-after-test-finishes-in-jmeter)

But would be nice to understand the issue, rather than just forcing the threads to stop.

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "understand" the issue you need to understand what this thread is doing and the only way to get the information is [taking a JVM thread dump](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/TakeThreadDump.html), the options are in:

1. Starting from [JMeter version 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32/) there is an option to take a thread dump directly from JMeter GUI

   [image]
2. You can use [`jstack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) tool and provide to it the PID of the Java process where JMeter is running
3. On Linux you can use [`kill -3`](https://linuxize.com/post/kill-command-in-linux/) command which will print the status of threads into the console window

You can also check `jmeter-server.log` for for any suspicious entries.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It was a thread group with a constant timer set to very high number that was making the thread to wait(30mins) I didn’t expect that to be there, my apologies for not seeing it before. After I removed it, the test finished in the time as expected. But in past I had seen issues like this so thought of reaching out. Your answer provided me additional tools to try and learn.